# android | smoothness is missing in swapping tabs having gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have two tabs in my application each having **gridview** holding 20+ **imageview**s. I successfully implemented what I want but problem is that when I swipe from first tab to the second, the transition is not smooth. I am using the same adapter for both the **gridview**s.

Below is my adapter implementation

```
public class LogoImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private List<Integer> logoIds;
    public LogoImageAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> logoIds) {
        this.context = context;
        this.logoIds = logoIds;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return logoIds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return logoIds.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return logoIds.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View gridView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        } else {
            gridView = convertView;
        }
        /*TextView title = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.siteNameTV);
            title.setText("Title_" + position);*/
        ImageView logoImage = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.logoImageView);
        logoImage.setImageResource(logoIds.get(position));
        return gridView;
    }
}
```

Please help me to get smooth tab transition.

**Edit: ViewPager implementation**

```
public class HomepageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar()!=null)
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the primary sections/tabs of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mShare:
                shareApplication();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Homepage();
                case 1:
                    return new Classified();
                case 2:
                    return new Tourism();
                case 3:
                    return new Shopping();
                case 4:
                    return new Travel();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // number of tabs.
            return Constants.TAB_NUMBER;
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return Constants.TAB_HOMEPAGE;
                case 1:
                    return Constants.TAB_CLASSIFIED;
                case 2:
                    return Constants.TAB_TOURISM;
                case 3:
                    return Constants.TAB_SHOPPING;
                case 4:
                    return Constants.TAB_TRAVEL;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your viewpager code look like?

Comment: @Jonathan727 I have updated my question with viewpager implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It seams you use same adapter to load images for two tabs and so there can be some delay. Then check your images sizes whether large or small size of images(High Resolutions). Because large size of images grid view may cause to make same delay when load the adapter. I also had that experience before and i reduce the size of images and reduce the delay.